# Dispatching files to directories using name pattern matching

Tags: bash, mv

Consider:

```
$ ls
about-bar   about-bar.pdf   about-foo   about-fou.pdf
$ for f in *about-*.pdf; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed -E 's:(about-.*).pdf:\1:')";done
$ find .
.
./about-bar
./about-bar/about-bar.pdf
./about-foo
./about-fou
```

What would be an efficient way to skip files that don't have a corresponding directory? In this case, only `about-bar.pdf` would be moved, and `about-fou.pdf` wouldn't be renamed (specifically, `.pdf` stripped).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `sed` needed here; we can use standard `bash` expression of `${file%.pdf}` to strip off the `.pdf` extension

```
$ ls
about-bar/  about-bar.pdf  about-foo/  about-fou.pdf

$ for a in *.pdf
> do
>   dir=${a%.pdf}
>   if [ -d "$dir" ]
>   then
>     mv -i "$a" "$dir"
>   fi
> done

$ ls
about-bar/  about-foo/  about-fou.pdf

$ ls *
about-fou.pdf

about-bar:
about-bar.pdf

about-foo:
```

Comment: It seems that you are suggesting a script, whereas I was trying to do it in one line. I expect the modified code to return:

Comment: That _was_ a single command line, just typed in over multiple lines for readability.  You can reformat it with `;` in the right place.    i.e.  `for a in *.pdf; do dir=${a%.pdf}; if [ -d "$dir" ]; then mv -i "$a" "$dir"; fi; done`

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. Would it be possible to use sed with the following change: `do dir=$(echo $f | sed ... )`? (which may accommodate more complex patterns than the one suggested by my example)

Comment: Right, and sometimes calling out to an external program like `sed` is the easiest way of doing it.  But it's not as efficient (especially for large directories), so I recommend avoiding it for the simple cases like this one.

Comment: Here's a version I just tested that accommodates a prefix before `about`: `$ ls
about-bar  about-fou.pdf
about-foo  bazabout-bar.pdf $ for f in *about-*.pdf; do dir="$(echo $f | sed -E 's:.*(about-.*).pdf:\1:')";echo $dir; done about-bar`